# How can an uppercase letter be turned into the corresponding lowercase one in ATS?

Tags: ats

Given a word (of the type string), I need to turn all of the letters in the given word into lowercase ones before looking it up in a dictionary. How can I do this? Is there a special function for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following function to uppercase a given string:

```
fun
string_toupper
(cs: string): string =
string_copywith(cs, lam(c) => $UN.cast{charNZ}(toupper(c)))
```

Or you can call string_toupper and string_tolower if you do

```
#include "libats/ML/BOXED/mylibies.hats"
```